# Storing a two-bit binary in char

Tags: c, binary, char, bit

So I'm working on a program that takes a file of characters and turns these into a file of characters of binary numbers. Then I have to be able to read these characters (the binary characters) and turn them back into the denoted characters.

So essentially this is encoding and decoding a file.

So I have a file with the four characters: '@', '/n', ':', ' '. (Last one is space)

So the reason I want to do this is that I have a bunch of ascii pictures that I want to store in smaller files.

I have been told that I can use an unsigned char, set it to 0, then read a file with the characters described above, and use bitwise operators to assign the values read into the unsigned char and then for each four characters read (because each character is 8 bites and these can then be turned into 2 bites each and stored in one character, hence four characters in one char) append (add) each number to the char.

Any help Appreciated!

The code I have now is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *inputFile;
FILE *outputFile;

int encodeBinary[4] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03};
char encodeChars[4] = {':', '@', '\n', ' '};

//reads from a file and creates the encoded file
void encode(const char * inFile, const char * outFile)
{

    inputFile = fopen(inFile, "r");
    outputFile = fopen(outFile, "w");
    char lineBuffer[BUFSIZ];
    int size = 0;
    char temp = 0;

    if(inputFile == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(fgets(lineBuffer, sizeof(lineBuffer), inputFile))
    {
        for(int i = 0; lineBuffer[i] != 0; i++)
        {

            //adds four different characters to a char before adding the character to the file
            if(size < 4) {
                if(lineBuffer[i] == encodeChars[0])
                {

                }
                else if(lineBuffer[i] == encodeChars[1])
                {

                }
                else if(lineBuffer[i] == encodeChars[2])
                {

                }
                else if(lineBuffer[i] == encodeChars[3])
                {

                }

                size++;
            } else {
                size = 0;
                temp = 0;

            }
        }
    }

    fclose(inputFile);
    fclose(outputFile);

}
```

Would really appreciate if someone could come up with some examples as how to add the bits read in to the temp char. I have no idea as to how I can add the numbers to the char so that they are moved in such a way and added in such a way as to represent the old numbers and the new. I'm thinking I can bitshift the number 3 times to the left, so that 01 becomes 0100.

Comment: What did you try? You've apparantly already been given pretty good instructions, now you have to try to figure out how to express those in code.

Comment: I tried to code it with four if tests to check what char we are reading, but I'm new to C so I have no idea how to append to a char using bits etc.

Comment: Do you know how to use bitwise operators: &, ^, >>, << ?

Comment: You should look up C bitwise operations, try some code, and show the code in your question for help.

Comment: Yes, I know the basics of bitwise operations, but I can't seem to figure out how to use them properly in this example. The idea that I have is to add each bit to the char, but I can't seem to get how because you can't append values to a char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using bitfields, you could use << and >> operators and bitwise & and | to manipulate the bits directly,

Encode,

```
unsigned char accum;

if(size>0) accum = encodeChars[0] << 6
if(size>1) accum |= encodeChars[0] << 4
if(size>2) accum |= encodeChars[0] << 2
if(size>3) accum |= encodeChars[0]
if(lineBuffer[i] accum
```

Decode,

```
char array[4];
if(size>0) array[0] = decodeChars[ (accum >> 6) &0x3 ];
if(size>1) array[1] = decodeChars[ (accum >> 4) &0x3 ];
if(size>2) array[2] = decodeChars[ (accum >> 2) &0x3 ];
if(size>3) array[3] = decodeChars[ (accum) &0x3  ];
```

and read about big-endian vs. little-endian to understand element storage order.

Comment: I would use bitfields only to improve readability, specially when encoding/decoding. Apart from this, your answer is the correct way of doing this (+1)

Comment: Why did you & with "&0x3"  in here `decodeChars[ (accum >> 6) &0x3 ];` ?

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said this needs a little thought. Your character has 8bits which can be divided into 4 2bit fields. So you initially need to set all the bits in the 8bit character to zero. Each character in the file will need to be encoded to a value between 0-3. Once you read a character in, you will need to find its encoding and create a mask of the encoded value. The mask will need to be shifted to an empty 2bit field within the 8bit character and ORed with it.

There are lots of implementation specific stuff left for you to do, but that is the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have an input char from file, we call it input_char;

```
unsigned char input_char;
```

you define:

```
typedef union
{
   struct
   {
      unsigned char first  :2;
      unsigned char second :2;
      unsigned char third  :2;
      unsigned char fourth :2;
   } two_bits;

   unsigned char byte;

} UNION_TWO_BITS_STORAGE;

UNION_TWO_BITS_STORAGE storage_char;
```

and then

```
storage_char.two_bits.first = (input_char & 0x03);
```

this is valid if only bits 0 and 1 of input_char are significative.  Otherwise, you need logical shifts right.

Or, you can have

```
unsigned char temp;

switch(input_char)
{
     case '@':
        temp = 0x00;
        break;

     case '/n':
        temp = 0x01;
        break;
etc...
```

and

```
storage_char.two_bits.first = (temp);
```

and, when you write character back to destiation file, you can just write

```
 storage_char.byte
```

Yes, it's a little messy, and you can write it in a more loopable way.  But it was only to show the concept of using a union, here

Answer (score 0):

another way to see what ChuckCottril says, using your code, is the following

```
    #include <stdio.h>
            #include <stdlib.h>
            #include <string.h>

    FILE *inputFile;
    FILE *outputFile;

    int encodeBinary[4] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03};
    char encodeChars[4] = {':', '@', '\n', ' '};


    //reads from a file and creates the encoded file
    void encode(const char * inFile, const char * outFile)
    {

        inputFile = fopen(inFile, "r");
        outputFile = fopen(outFile, "w");
        char lineBuffer[BUFSIZ];
        int size = 0;
        char temp = 0;
        char output_char;

        if(inputFile == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error while opening file.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        output_char = 0;

        while(fgets(lineBuffer, sizeof(lineBuffer), inputFile))
        {
            for(int i = 0; lineBuffer[i] != 0; i++)
            {

                //adds four different characters to a char before adding the character to the file
                if(size < 4) {
                    if(lineBuffer[i] == encodeChars[0])
                    {
                       temp = encodeBinary[0];
                    }
                    else if(lineBuffer[i] == encodeChars[1])
                    {
                       temp = encodeBinary[1];
                    }
                    else if(lineBuffer[i] == encodeChars[2])
                    {
                       temp = encodeBinary[2];
                    }
                    else if(lineBuffer[i] == encodeChars[3])
                    {
                       temp = encodeBinary[3];
                    }

                    output_char |= temp << (size*2);

                    size++;
                } else {

                    //PRINT TO FILE OUTPUT CHAR, or save to output buffer
                    size = 0;
                    temp = 0;
                    output_char = 0;

                }
            }
        }

        fclose(inputFile);
        fclose(outputFile);

    }
```

Be aware of one thing: you should always have input file with a multiple of 4 Bytes, otherwise decode can result in a different file!